# Dynamic delay in Verilog/SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to make a delay statement that the quantity of the delay varies with time, it could possibly increase or decrease. I need a statement to occur when the simulation time is equal to some variable (call it delay),the variable delay is continuously changed by other parallel processes, no synthesis is required. Here is an example:

```
module test();

  logic flag;
  integer delay=10;
  initial begin
      flag=0;
       #1;
       delay=2;
       flag=1;
       #1
       delay=20;
       flag=0;
  end
  always @ (flag) begin
       $display("Inside flag always block at time: %0t with delay of %d", $realtime,delay); 
       #delay 
       flag=~flag;
       $display("Flag changed to %d at time: %0t", flag, $realtime);
  end


endmodule
```

In other words, I need to interrupt (reset) the always @ (flag) statement with any change in the flag even before the internal delay finishes and re-perform the #delay statement with the new delay values.

The ideas that I thought of:

1- recast the code logic by making it sensitive to a fictitious clock that toggles every time step of the simulator. But I think this is hugely resources consuming, especially if the aim of my code is to speed up the simulation.

2- Use of Fork/Join statement to create multiple threads each one corresponds to a change in the value of the delay (using dynamically array memory allocation of the delay variable) but the issue is how to make dynamic statements in the fork block.

Finally, I got the feeling that this is not possible by any means, is there a workaround?

Comment: I'd say that you do not provide sufficient information about your requirements. For example,  there is no info on how the variable changes. Is this change synced with a  clock? What *should* happen if  delay changed while the other is active. You hinted that it should be interrupted, right? In this case you must forget about the always block and do the delay via some behavior loop within a task. You can possibly get away with two fork threads, one generating some delay trigger and the other disabling the first if delay changes prematurely.

Comment: Hi Serge, the delay variables changes asynchronously, not synched with any clock. What do you mean by the other? The point is, in my above code, if it passes and I could interrupt the always block before the internal delay finishes then my whole problem will be solved. The point is, the delay could change multiple times not only 1 time, that's why I have written in my second idea that I need to write dynamically number of statement in the fork threads. what do you mean by " behavior loop within a task" is not that the same as idea-1 ?

Comment: You need to give us an example of what expected behavior you are looking for. This is an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @MohamedOsama there is no way to interrupt an always block. But your task could be done in a different manner.

Comment: @dave_59 for example at my above code I want only the last delay to occur, which is (20), simply I need to interrupt (break) the on-going delay if the sensitivity list changed.

Comment: @MohamedOsama, you need to provide an example that shows the desired sinulus and output. Then we can focus on the best way to implement. For example, what would happen if the delay was 20, then 10 time units later you change the delay to 8. What is the required behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate what I said about a loop in comments. Here are two loops: one controls a delay counter (via $time) and the other controls the delayed *flag*. The always block reacts to the flag.

```
module test;
  int delay;
  bit flag;
  time start;
  
  initial begin
    forever begin
      @(delay) begin
        $display("%0t: delay for %d", $time, delay);
        start = $time;
      end
    
    end
  end
  
  initial begin
    forever begin
      #1
      if ($time - start == delay)
        flag = 1;
      
    end
  end
  
  initial begin
    delay = 0;
    #3 delay = 10;
    #30 delay = 5;
    #10 delay = 10;
    #22 delay = 20;
    #10 delay = 11;
    
    #100 $finish;
  end
  
  always @(flag) begin
    if (flag) begin
      $display ("%0t, delayed", $time);
        flag = ~flag;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

first 3 delays work uninterrupted. the last one (20) is interrupted by (11). The rest of algorithm is up to you.

Note: This is a quick and dirty v2k-style implementation just to illustrate the concept. It can be done better in svtb.

Comment: Thank you for the code but this is almost the first idea I wrote, you simply force the simulator to work inside the second initial block at every time step because of the #1. This is somehow resource consuming. I wanted something to speed up the simulation further..

Comment: There is not much of the resource consuming here, in particular because of #1: a simple comparison every simulation tick.  I do not see any other way to do what you want.

Comment: This is what  I felt too, thanks anyway..